# What is the best practice to store a specification of an Entity in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My database contain products in a single table called `Product`, and each product might have certain fields with their specification, e.g.

```json
//Bicycle product
{
    "name" : "Bicycle",
    "category" : "Bicycles"
    "specification" : {
        "color" : "red"
    }
}

//Wheel product
{
    "name" : "Wheel",
    "category" : "Spare Parts",
    "specification" : {
        "diameter" : "7.5"
    }
}
```

So i've come up with idea of making a field of type `Map<String, String>` (which creates a another table called specifications) in my `Product` entity to contain those specifications. But i don't like this approach, because all of the additional fields would be of String type, and because Spring will create a bean out of this field, I wont be able to specify the type of value as an abstract class (like this `Map<String, Object>`).

I thought of creating additional fields, like this:

```java
@ElementCollection
    private Map<String, String> string_features;
@ElementCollection
    private Map<String, Double> double_features;
// ...
```

But it looks kind of ugly and I think there is a better way to do it. And also, if the specification field is of a different Entity type, I will have to create another map for that specific entity, e.g.

```
//Bicycle product
{
    "name" : "Bicycle",
    "category" : "Bicycles"
    "specification" : {
        "color" : "red",
        "wheel" : {
            "name" : "Wheel",
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value can be only be numbers and strings, maybe you can save the value as strings and then use a regex to check if the string is a number before returning the value.

Otherwise, you need a way to recognize the type.
I think I would change it to this:

```
//Bicycle product
{
    "name" : "Bicycle",
    "category" : "Bicycles"
    "specifications" : [
        { name: "color", value: "red", type: "string"},
        { name: "diameter", value: "7.5", type: "double"},
        ...
     ]
}
```

You can map it as:

```
@ElementCollection
private List<Specification> specifications;

...

@Embaddable
class Specification {
   String name;
   String value;
   String type;

   // ... getter/setter and everything else

   @Transient
   Object getConvertedValue() {
      if ("double".equals(type)) {
          return Double.parse(value);
      }
      // String is the default
      return value;
   }
}
```

The nice thing is that you can have as many types as you want.

Comment: By the way, there is probably a way to store the type mapping it as `Class<?> type`. Then you could read the value as `type.cast(value)`.